# Pegando o total em pixels de um elemento passado em variável em porcentagem

Tags: jquery, css

Estou montando uma `div` que deve ser um quadrado exato, porém esse quadrado deve se basear no próprio `width` que está sendo setado com `pocentagem` (%), porém preciso do valor total em `pixels`.

```
EX: 5% = 105px

var larguraVideoItemFirst = $('.video-item-first').width()//retorna 5 pois foi setado 5%.
$('.video-item-first').css({'height':larguraVideoItemFirst + 'px'}); //converte usando os 5% como pixel, ficando 5px.
```

Comment: O `width()` não retorna a porcentagem e sim a largura do elemento em `px` mesmo que a mesma seja definida em `%`.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes o elemento tem 465px de largura, definido como 32% em width, e quando dou console.log ele retorna 32px

Comment: veja aqui um exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/pueogbxx/1/ o seu problema deve ser outro. O código que está na pergunta, é o código utilizado no projeto ou é só um exemplo? Coloque na sua pergunta o seu HTML também.

Comment: é o código usado

Comment: Murilo, tire as imagens e coloque como texto formatado como código, com imagens não conseguimos copiar o código.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você não precisa de `JavaScript` para manter a proporção entre `Width` e `Height`, se quiser manter o `Height` proporcional ao `Width`, set o `Height` com `vw (viewport width)`.

Se precisar que o Width seja proporcional ao Height, set o `Width` com `vh (viewport  height)`.

Como você quer um quadrado perfeito, ou seja uma proporção de 1:1, então o `vw` do `height` será igual a `%` do `width`.

Segue um exemplo abaixo.:

```css
.bloco {
  float: left;  
}

.bloco20 {
  background-color: teal;
  width: 19%;
  height: 19vw;
  margin: 0.5%;
}

.bloco40 {
  background-color: crimson;
  width: 39%;
  height: 39vw;
  margin: 0.5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bloco bloco20"></div>
<div class="bloco bloco20"></div>
<div class="bloco bloco20"></div>
<div class="bloco bloco20"></div>
<div class="bloco bloco20"></div>
<div class="bloco bloco40"></div>
<div class="bloco bloco40"></div>
<div class="bloco bloco20"></div>
<div class="bloco bloco20"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

O método `width` obtém a largura computada atual do elemento em questão (dê uma lida na [documentação](http://api.jquery.com/width/) do jQuey).

Então o valor de `$('.video-item-first').width()` será em `px` e não em porcentagem.

O Chrome possue o [inspetor de elementos](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/), utilize-o e veja que o elemento possui a largura renderizada em `px`.

Veja o exemplo abaixo, eu defini que a largura do elemento será de `30%` mas o método `width` retorna o valor em `px`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $quadrado = $('.quadrado');
 var w = $quadrado.width();
  
  $quadrado.height(w + 'px');
  $quadrado.html("O quadrado tem " + w + "px de largura.");  
});
```

```css
.quadrado {
  display:block;
  float:left;
  width: 30%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="quadrado"></div>
```

**Casos em que o valor poderá não corresponder a largura do elemento renderizado ou coincidir com o valor em porcentagem:**

- O elemento pai ter `100px` de largura e a largura em `px` irá coincidir com o valor em `%`.
- Ao utilizar a propriedade `class`, o método `width` retorna o valor correspondente ao primeiro elemento encontrado (veja [um exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/pueogbxx/2/)), logo o segundo elemento poderá ter uma segunda classe (ou estilo ***inline***) que modifique a largura dando a entender que o cálculo está errado.
- O javascript é executado antes da renderização do elemento.
- JQuery (v3.1.1) retorna a porcentagem se você consultar o valor muito cedo (quando o DOM ainda não está pronto) e em seu CSS você especificou uma porcentagem.

Comment: não funciona, como já mencionado na questão, o valor retornado é o mesmo definido em porcentagem, não é o valor equivalente, no caso, retorna 32%, como 32px

Comment: @MuriloGambôa você está a fazer uma questão que não faz sentido, a documentação diz o que descrevi acima e ainda insiste que o problema é da biblioteca? Não existe resposta para a pergunta que você postou, então o que escrevi acima é um pequeno guia para você mudar de direção e procurar o problema real. Chegou pelo menos a ver o exemplo que postei na resposta? Não entendo a dificuldade em perceber isso muito menos o voto negativo.

Comment: o próprio jquery está retornando o valor em porcentagem, vou printar aqui e adicionar à pergunta

Comment: eu vi o exemplo, e testei na minha div, não rodou

Comment: @MuriloGambôa deve ser algum engano seu, o retorno é sempre px, a não ser que seja algum bug do navegador.

Comment: entao deve ser bug na versao mais recente do chrome...  mas a outra resposta do cara la funcionou